# How can I install Camera Raw 15.2 for Adobe Photoshop CS6?

Tags: photoshop, adobe-camera-raw, windows-10

I have Photoshop CS6 Extended installed, Camera Raw worked fine with photos from a 6-year old camera but not with a current model.
I installed Adobe Camera Raw 15.2 from a file AdobeCameraRaw_x64_15_2.exe without seeing any problems. However Photoshop and Bridge still do not recognize files from the new camera - when opening Camera Raw it reports version 9.1.1 .

I find a folder with the name of my current camera in C:\ProgramData\Adobe\CameraRaw\CameraProfiles\Camera.

Question: How do I fix this problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about software compatibility and not about photography per se.

Comment: E.g. you do not need Photoshop to use Camera RAW, you can just install Adobe Bridge. It needs to be licensed though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Romeo's answer says, the newest Camera Raw is not compatible with your Photoshop version.

An alternative solution is to download the Adobe DNG Convertor, see https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/using/adobe-dng-converter.html. This is a free download that does not require any subscription.

This convertor should allow you to convert RAW files even from recent camera models to DNG files that are compatible with older versions of Adobe software.

https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/using/adobe-dng-converter.html#compatibility_preferences explicitly explains how to select a compatible DNG version.

Comment: That was my "Plan B", and it works (at least I got no problems so far).

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Adobe document](https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/camera-raw-compatible-applications.html) the maximum compatible version of CameraRAW you can use with Photoshop CS6 is 9.1.1